# How to shuffle (not randomly) a list in Python?

Tags: python

I analyze information that I retrieve from csv files that are in a folder.
I read these files in alphabetical order and build two lists from what I read:

`l`, which is the list that retrieves the names of the files (without the extension).

`resu`, which is the list containing the information I'm interested in these files.

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
resu = [150,43,35,49,53,27]
```

I draw plt.bar from this information and I would like to draw them in a certain order to be able to interpret them better.

I would like to put the files in this order : `'a','b','d','f','e','c'`.

I have written :

```
(l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5])=(l[3],l[5],l[4],l[2])
(resu[2],resu[3],resu[4],resu[5])=(resu[3],resu[5],resu[4],resu[2])
```

Is there a way to do this more easily and quickly ?
I have thought of using the list of new item indexes : `[0,1,3,5,4,2]` but I haven't found how I could use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, which is similar to your approach but less repetitive:

```py
>>> order = ['a','b','d','f','e','c']
>>> [resu[l.index(key)] for key in order]
[150, 43, 49, 27, 53, 35]
```

You can do the same for `l` but you'll just get `order` back, so you might as well use `order` directly.

---

A nicer way is to convert your data to a dictionary first:

```py
>>> d = dict(zip(l, resu))
>>> d
{'a': 150, 'b': 43, 'c': 35, 'd': 49, 'e': 53, 'f': 27}
>>> [d[key] for key in order]
[150, 43, 49, 27, 53, 35]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the idea of the dictionnary, it is a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Listcomp with `list.index`?

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> change = ['a','b','d','f','e','c']
>>> resu = [150,43,35,49,53,27]

>>> [resu[l.index(idx)] for idx in change]

[150, 43, 49, 27, 53, 35]
```

Comment: It's a list comprehension, not a generator. But the code works :)

Comment: Always mix listcomp and genexp, looks almost identical to me while it isn't.

Comment: A list comprehension produces a list (the square brackets in the syntax are not an accident), a generator expression produces... a generator :)

Comment: No way I misunderstood it, wouldn't ```[*(genexp)]``` be same with *listcomp*? In that context I tend to consider *listcomp* as syntax-sugar - Seems like this also violates *In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess*, but I really don't know why *listcomp* was designed as separated keyword.

Comment: The answer is historic: list comprehensions were added first ([PEP 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), Python 2.0), and generator expressions came after ([PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), Python 2.4).

Comment: So *PEP 289* was to replace *listcomp* in some use cases where only *iterator* protocol is enought - now it's crystal-clear. Thanks for references.

Answer (score 0):

Generic function to reorder any amount of lists:

```
def reorder(order, *lists):
    result = []
    for l in lists:
        result.append([])
        for i in order:
            result[-1].append(l[i])
    return result
```

Usage:

```
l, resu = reorder([0,1,3,5,4,2], l, resu)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator with map

```
order = [0,1,3,5,4,2]
resu = map(l.__getitem__, order)
```

most simple things that accept a list will accept the iterator as an input,
if you need a list specifically you can add the `list()` over the map like this

```
resu = list(map(l.__getitem__, order))
```